# how to end code inside an if statement if a letter is typed?

Tags: python, if-statement

hi i want to end the code if a letter is typed in Cost1 but im not sure how to do that i want it to be only a number in there. any help is appreciated.( the .isletter is just filler for an example)

```
Item1 = input("What item do you want to buy? ") # asking what item is
if Item1.isdigit():
  exit("ERROR")

Cost1 = input("How much does this item cost? ") # asking cost of item
if Cost1.isletter():
  exit("ERROR")
```

Comment: This code will "end" no matter what you enter for Cost1.

Comment: @ScottHunter what makes you think so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and, in the future, try to [find solutions yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). To find the linked duplicate, I tried using `[python] string is letter` in the site search. Trying something [similar in a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+string+is+letter) also works very well.

Comment: "what makes you think so?" The fact that there is no more code to run afterwards, I imagine.

Comment: That said, no matter what the user types, the result will be **a string**, and **not** a number. I added another duplicate about the overall problem that you seem to want to solve.

Answer (score -3):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
if 'a' in ascii_lowercase:
    print("letter")
```

Comment: What question is this meant to be answering?

Comment: How to check if a letter is entered for `input()`. I assumed people will know how to replace literal `'a'` with a variable.